# Stop playing parent frame HTML5 audio from an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, iframe

Quick question: I have an HTML document playing HTML5 Audio. Nothing fancy. Textbook really.

```
<audio id="audioclip" preload="auto" loop >
    <source src="audio/music01.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  </audio>
```

The same HTML document features an iframe containing a few Images. Clicking on one of these images browses to a page containing an autostart HTML5 video clip.

Of course now the audio from the parent AND the audio from the iframe video play at the same time.

Is there an EASY way to stop the parent audio playback from *inside* the iframe automatically when the autoplay video triggers?

I found some pretty complicated stuff for parent/child communication. Far to sophisticated for me. But I also found this little snippet:

```
jQuery(function($) {  
    parent.$("#parent_element").trigger(event); 
} (window.jQuery));
```

Could I put that to use in my case?

Or are there alternatives?

Just getting into JavaScript a little more, atm I'd consider myself a newbie. :-\

Many Thanks!

PS: On video end the iframe page automatically browses back to the previous page. It would be super-nifty if the audio would resume playing at the Point IF it was playing before. If not then...well...not.  But I reckon that would be much more complex?